# Bitlocker is not available for my second hard drive

Tags: windows-8.1, bitlocker

I encrypted my C: drive using bitlocker. Although my notebook doesn't have TPM, I changed the Local Computer Policy to enable bitlocker without TPM and it worked just fine.

I want to do the same with drive d, but option (turn on bitlocker) is not there when I right click the drive.

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro.

**Drive c: right-click:**

[image: Bitlocker working just fine. Drive C:]

**Drive d: right-click:**

[image: Bitlocker option missing. Drive D:]

**Disk Management**

[image: Disk Management]

Comment: Why is your system disk D instead of C?

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, my system disk is C, not D. I'm not sure why C is "disk 1" instead of "disk 0", though. Probably because of their order on the sata interfaces. It boots just fine on drive c.

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows your D drive as being the system disk.

Comment: You're clearly right. And I have no idea why. How can that be? Windows is installed on drive c. Should I panic?

Comment: I have exact the same case. One of my drives (F:) has only data file howeveris marked with "System". Probably this is the reason I cannot enable the BitLocker on it.