# Move the bootloader to the drive with the system root

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bootloader

My windows 10 installation is on (C:) drive ("Boot" label), however the Boot Loader ("System" label) resides on another disk (F:).

Here is the Disk Management:
[image]

Is there a safe way to move the Boot Loaded from the (F:) drive to (C:) without formatting the (C:) drive which has the windows installation ?

Comment: Just curious, why would you like to do this? Tampering with the bootloader might render your installation of Windows unusable.

Comment: @Todd Because this prevents the BitLocker from being enabled on that particular disk (F:).

Comment: I don't understand, BitLocker can be enabled on system disks, being labeled as a system disk shouldn't prevent you from encrypting the disk with BitLocker.

Comment: @Ramhound BitLocker is done for Disk1 (D:) and it is available for Disk 2 (C:). However it is NOT for Disk 0 (F:) and I suspect I have the same conditions with this: https://superuser.com/questions/774367/bitlocker-is-not-available-for-my-second-hard-drive  . The common unusual factor is the "System" label being on that irrelevant particular disk. Even if this will not enable the BitLocker, it is something that I need to do in case I want to remove my data Disk (F:) from this desktop.

Comment: Just for completeness. The windows installation that resides on M2 is a cloned image that was on the SSD (Disk 1). It sems that the process I followed back in time, was missing a step letting the boot loader to be assgined to the first (Disk 0) or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Created an 100 MB partition **in the front of** C: disk using the "MiniTool Partition Wizard". The actions were: shrink, move, allocate, format, assign letter, set "active" label
2. Created a Rescue Media DVD using the Macrium Reflect (just in case)
3. Booted from the Rescue Media using the "Macrium Reflect" tool
4. Fixed all boot problems with "Fix boot problems" leaving all **4 options enabled**
5. Disconnect all other disks, set boot priority on BIOS to check that the system boots from M2
6. Checked that the "System" label has been moved from the F: disk to C: using the "MiniTool Partition Wizard"
7. Backup, format and restore the data on D: and F: disks to get rid of the "active" labels. I could remove the label using the "MiniTool Partition Wizard"
8. Enabled the BitLocker in all 3 disks C: D: and F:

The disk manager looks like this:

[image: Disk manager]